# PHP чтение TXT файла в массив, правка и запись обратно в TXT

Tags: php, массивы

Помогите дописать - закипел!

Есть текстовый файл с содержимым:

```
111;0.1
222;0.2
333;0.3
444;0.4
```

Необходимо:

1. сравнить переменные $a=555 и $b=0.5 с последней строкой, если $a > 444, то удалить первую строку и добавить новые данные последней строкой:

```
222;0.2
333;0.3
444;0.4
555;0.5
```

2. а если $a = 444, но $b > 0.4, то изменить последнюю строку:

```
111;0.1
222;0.2
333;0.3
444;0.5
```

Новая переменная $a каждый раз будет увеличиваться (это текущее время в сек. - для наглядности обозначил 111,222,333)

**Проблема:** при записи сбивается содержимое файла - много пустых строк и только пару значений (точно показать не могу, т.к. работает в потоке и отследить одно тестовое изменение невозможно)

```
<?php

$a=555;
$b=0.5;

$file = 'file.txt';
$lines = file($file);
$last = explode(";", array_pop($lines)); //последний элемент массива
$old_A=$last[0];
$old_B=$last[1];
if($old_A == $a){
    if($b > $old_B) //если новый больше старого
        array_push($lines, $old_A.";".$b); // добавим новый в массив
        else
        array_push($lines, $old_A.";".$old_B); // вернем старый в массив
    file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
} else {
    unset($lines[0]); // удаляем первый элемент массива
    array_push($lines, $old_A.";".$old_B);
    array_push($lines, $old_A.";".$b);
    file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
}
file_put_contents($file, $old_A.";".$b.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот сам решил

```
<?php
$a = 1000;
$b = 0.2;
$file="data.txt";
$file_lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$last_line = explode(";", end($file_lines));
if ($a > $last_line[0]) {
  array_shift($file_lines);
  $file_lines[] = $a . ";" . $b;
} elseif ($a == $last_line[0]) {
  $file_lines[count($file_lines) - 1] = $a . ";" . $b;
}
file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $file_lines));
?>
```